# Using multiple states in one component is causing the component to render over and over again. Does this affect the app? How can I fix this?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React,{useState} from "react"

const Pagination = ()=>{
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    data: [],
    recordsTotal: 0,
  });
  return (
     <div> 
       
     </div>
  );}
```

Using multiple states in one component is causing the component to render over and over again. Does this affect the app? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the state updates ? The problem is most probably there.

Answer (score 0):

**Re-renders and use of React.Memo**

The first thing to address is when a React component re-renders. React components schedule a re-render *whenever the state of that component changes.* Not only will that component re-render, but any child components, regardless of whether they take any properties, will re-render as well.

If your Pagination component is used by a parent component, and that parent component re-renders due to a state change, then Pagination too will re-render, even though it has no properties.

You can prevent re-render of this particular component using `React.memo` ([see here for Pure Components and React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)). Implementation `React.memo` will prevent re-render if, given the same properties (yours has none), the previous render is returned and no re-render occurs. Important to note that a Pagination will still re-render correctly if it has state changes itself.

```
import React,{useState} from "react"

const Pagination = React.memo(()=>{
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    data: [],
    recordsTotal: 0,
  });
  return (
     <div> 
       
     </div>
  );})
```

**Strict Mode**

The final point I'd make is in development mode, if you're using `<React.StrictMode>` in your index.js, it forces renders to occurs twice ([as per here](https://hy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)). This does not occur in production mode so there's nothing to worry about.